# Custom select on checkout page Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Using ACF in Woocommerce on the checkout page where I created a custom checkout field for selecting the delivery method.

How to make it so that when you click the "Confirm order" button, the selected select field is passed to the total order itself, and sent in the order letter.

I create this repeater field in checkout-form.php file:

```
/**
 * Checkout Form
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

// If checkout registration is disabled and not logged in, the user cannot checkout
if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_enabled() && $checkout->is_registration_required() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    return;
}

?>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

        <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
            <div class="col-12">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
            </div>
                <?php if( have_rows('shipping_methods') ): ?>
                    <div class="shipp-method">
                        <label for="shipping_method">Способ доставки:</label>
                        <select name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method" class="select_shipping">
                             <?php while( have_rows('shipping_methods') ): the_row(); 
                             $method = get_sub_field('shipping_method');
                             ?> 
                                <option><?php echo $method; ?></option>
                           <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>    
                <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="col-12">
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

    <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

Comment: This question is not completely clear… where do you want that data to appear exactly and with which label?

Comment: Has corrected the question in a post. Created a custom field in the checkout-form.php file using the advanced custom field plug-in. I need it so that I can add delivery fields from the admin panel.

Comment: And what about woocommerce default shipping methods functionality? You can't replace them with any custom field like… Now I can show you how save your custom checkout field value in the order, **but it will not replace woocommerce shipping methods and functionalities**.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `ACF` field is not enough to add custom fields to Woocommerce checkout.

Woocommerce provide couple of filters so its checkout form fields can be modified, the most prominent one is: `woocommerce_checkout_fields`. While you can use ACF create a set of options for the additional select field you want to have in Woocommerce checkout form, you need to register them with the filter. For example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', function($fields) {
     // Get the field you need here and mutate $fields
     ...
     return $fields;
});
```

Doing so with make sure the data will be passed to the server. You also need to save them as an `order meta` to the database with the action `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`. Example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', function( $order_id) {
   update_post_meta( $order_id, [Your custom field name], sanitize_text_field( $_POST['your_custom_field_name']));
});
```

Also, a note here is that by default, Woocommerce provide shipping function out of the box already, which mean you probably don't want to reinvent the wheel. If you want to add your own additional shipping methods, you may want to look into how to create custom shipping method.

More on how to custom Woocommerce checkout:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

And custom shipping:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098

Comment: I need to register several fields, for example the repeater 'shipping_methods' itself and already the field in it, and I understand this function only one parameter